# How can I pass an object from fetchedResultsController to a custom cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to send an object, from a fetchedResultsController, to a custom cell.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
// ...
        TWMainViewExpandedCell *cell = (TWMainViewExpandedCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:StandardExpandedCellIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = (TWMainViewExpandedCell *)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MainViewStandardCellExpanded" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
        }

        Work *work = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.workInfo = work; // <- NSLog work.description confirms object exists!
        return cell;
// ...
}
```

And from my Custom Cell's .h and .m file

**.h**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) Work *workInfo;
```

**.m**

```
- (void) awakeFromNib {
    // ...
    NSLog(@"%@", _workInfo); // <- why is this nil?
    // ...
}
```

_workInfo, is returning nil! What am I missign here? How can I pass an object to my custom cell?

I can perfectly set up a text label, but not send an object from my FRC?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awakeFromNib` happens before you set `workInfo` (and it isn't going to be called at all if the cell is being reused). The normal thing to do here is write a custom property setter for `workInfo` like

```
- (void)setWorkInfo:(Work *)work
{
    if (_work != work) {
        _work = work;
        //make any Work-related updates to the cell here
    }
}
```

and make any Work-related updates to the cell inside the setter.